# transition using .css() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(".target").hover(function () {
    $(".element").css({
        "visibility": "visible",
            "opacity": 1,
            "transition": "visibility 0s linear 0.25s,opacity 0.25s linear"
    });
}, function () {
    $(".element").css({
        "visibility": "hidden",
            "opacity": 0,
            "transition": "visibility 0s linear 0.25s,opacity 0.25s linear"
    });
});
```

The mouseleave show the transition but not when I mouse over the .element, what's wrong with above code?

Comment: Can you provide us with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Did you really need the Jquery for this? Why not `.target:hover` css only ??

Comment: ^ Does anyone ever really need to use jQuery? No. It's lazy.

Comment: Just removed 0.25s after linear and it started working. No reason. So not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:-

```
$(".target").hover(function () {
    $(".element").css({
        "visibility": "hidden",
            "opacity": 0,
            "transition": "visibility 0s linear 0.25s,opacity 0.25s linear"
    });
}, function () {
    $(".element").css({
        "visibility": "visible",
            "opacity": 1,
            "transition": "visibility 0s linear 0.25s,opacity 0.25s linear"
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm no 100 percent sure if this is what you want, but here I create an easy fiddle for you using jQuery:

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/n97fs/2/

***JavaScript:***

```
$('.target').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('#element').fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.target').on('mouseout', function(){
    $('#element').fadeOut('slow');
});
```